# Post method in servlet is not getting values from JSP

Tags: image, jsp, servlets

I tried to find this error on the internet, but I could not solve my issue. 
I'm trying to save an image in a local folder in my project and I used the following tutorial to do that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html

I received no error when I compile the code, but I received a NullPointerException. This is my jsp:

```
 <form action="uploadImagem.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
       name="productForm" id="productForm"><br><br>
<form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        File:
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br/>
        Destination:
        <input type="text" value="/tcc_SI_M_12 - 12-10-2016_v1/images" name="destination" disabled/>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
    </form>
```

And this is my servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/uploadImagem.do")
public class uploadImagem extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final static Logger LOGGER = 
        Logger.getLogger(FileUpload.class.getCanonicalName());


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Create path components to save the file
    final String path = request.getParameter("destination");
    System.out.println("Parametros: " + path);
    final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    final String fileName = getFileName(filePart);


    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStream filecontent = null;
    final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + File.separator
                + fileName));
        filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

        int read = 0;
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + path);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "File{0}being uploaded to {1}", 
                new Object[]{fileName, path});
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
        writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
                + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
                + "location.");
        writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problems during file upload. Error: {0}", 
                new Object[]{fne.getMessage()});
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
        if (filecontent != null) {
            filecontent.close();
        }
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}

private String getFileName(final Part part) {
    final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Part Header = {0}", partHeader);
    for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return content.substring(
                    content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Please, mind that I've made some changes in the tutorial above. Also, I included and System.out to show me the valor in the variables and I received **null**.

Can you please help me?

Thank's a lot!

Comment: Why didn't you include @MultipartConfig in your Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two forms? remove the below code:

```
<form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```